# What type of Generalized Linear Model can handle high-to-low-variance heteroscedasticity?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, link-function

I am trying to model the relationship between a continuous response variable (sample-corrected species-diversity estimates) and a continuous predictor variable (geographic spread). I have log-transformed both variables to make the relationship linear.

I am investigating the use of Generalized Linear Models because my response variable is strongly heteroscedastic:
[image],

However, discussions about how to address heteroscedasticity in GLMs all seem to concern cases where variance in the response increases as the predictor variable increases. My problem is the reverse — high variance in species diversity at low values of geographic spread, decreasing as geographic spread increases.

Is there a GLM link function that can cope with this type of heteroscedasticity?

Comment: Can you explain how this "sample-correction" was done?

Comment: It's quite complicated (http://bio.mq.edu.au/%7Ejalroy/SQS.html), but the upshot is that counts are turned into continuous values.

Comment: You can't transform discrete counts into continuous values. Maybe continuous values are being generated in some way based on discrete variables. Unfortunately the link is less not at all clear about what is being done mathematically (let alone why). Is the procedure actually explained somewhere? (documenting inputs and outputs to R functions is of little value) ...

Comment: what concerns me is that counts generally have variance that increases with mean. If I can understand what was done to these counts I (or someone else) might be able to suggest a suitable way to analyze them.

Comment: It's not a transformation — it's a method that ensures even coverage of underlying species-abundance distributions. The values are continuous because it's the geometric mean of a large number of subsampling trials. The variance decreases with larger geographic areas because I'm subsampling area from a continental region, and there's more opportunity for wide variation in species composition with smaller geographic subsamples.

Comment: "a method that ensures even coverage of underlying species-abundance distributions" ... okay but *how*? "The values are continuous because it's the geometric mean of a large number of subsampling trials" -- nope, that's still discrete (despite the claim otherwise at the link), but it might be well approximated by a continuous distribution, perhaps. However, taking the geometric mean may be what's making the variance behave as it does; I still don't know what is going on. It will be difficult for people ato give meaningful advice on this basis.

Comment: SQS is a non-parametric alternative to [rarefaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarefaction_(ecology)) for subsampling fossil datasets. Rarefaction attempts to correct for biases in the fossil record by drawing uniform samples across different time intervals (or different geographic regions, etc.; for simplicity I'll refer to time intervals). However, uniform doesn't necessarily mean fair: for example, if the true, underlying pool of species richness increased from one time interval to the next, uniform sampling would draw a smaller fraction of those species. …

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37003/discussion-between-roger-and-glen-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to find an error distribution that could account for decreasing variance with increasing mean in a GLM, I opted to use Weighted Least Squares with weights inversely proportional to the relative variance.